# Advice on how to create GLSL 2D soft smoke/cloud shader

Tags: shader, pixel-shader, fragment-shader

I want to recreate this smoke/cloud effect which is used in the Arrival (2016) movie end credits.

I uploaded a sped up version of the credits to see the smoke dynamics.

[image: thumbnail]

*http://streamable.com/n3309 49s x6 sped up video of the credits*

I know how shaders work and can comfortably implement simple GLSL fragment shaders, but looking at this I can't seem to find a way to get started.

Starting points I considered:

- *Using a noise function:* Every noise function I could find looks unnatural and unsmooth. Not what I need.
- *Creating 2D/3D particle simulation:* This seems a bit overkill and even then I need functions that do not look calculated.
- *Just use some sprites and transform them randomly around:* That's lame and still looks 'fake'.

If you could guide me to a starting point on how to accomplish a somewhat similar looking GLSL shader implementation that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noise functions are definitely your friend here—[FBM](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fractalterraingeneration/wikis/Fractional_Brownian_Motion.wiki) would be one good candidate. You’re right that it can look too uniform on its own, but if you blend multiple layers of it together, using different speeds / directions for each and maybe distorting their domains a bit, you should be able to get very close to the look of that footage. There’s lots of clever uses of noise functions on [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=tag=noise&sort=popular); for an example of something like the approach described above, check out [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mtd3W7).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. FBM seems like a suitable noise function to recreate the footage.

Answer (score 5):

There is good glsl source of noise (simplex noise) [online](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/tree/master/src) to make real time noise. In addition to this, to make effect of moving fog/smoke like in this video you can make 3D FBM function. This is my function:

```
float default3DFbm(vec3 P, float frequency, float lacunarity, int octaves, float addition)
{
    float t = 0.0f;
    float amplitude = 1.0;
    float amplitudeSum = 0.0;
    for(int k = 0; k < octaves; ++k)
    {
        t += min(snoise(P * frequency)+addition, 1.0) * amplitude;
        amplitudeSum += amplitude;
        amplitude *= 0.5;
        frequency *= lacunarity;
    }
    return t/amplitudeSum;
}
```

Where `snoise` is 3D noise function from link and `P` is used to seed noise, for example

```
P = vec3(texcoord, uniform_speed)
```

Where `uniform_speed` is uniform variable incremented each frame with some value.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. The codebase you linked and the sample you provided helped me understand and implement my own function.